# macOS App .documentDirectory in App Extension

Tags: swift, macos, filesystems, macos-app-extension

I've faced an issue, where while I'm trying to get .documentDirectory from my app, I get `/Users/<Username>/Documents`

But when I'm trying to do exact same thing from App Extension I get `/Users/<Username>/Library/Containers/<Extension Bundle Identifier>/Data/`

So the question is: Is there any possible way to get `/Users/<Username>/Documents` from App Extension.

Code that I'm trying to use to get .documentDirectory:

```
guard let documents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
     return
}

print(documents.path)
```

Comment: Is your App extension sandboxed?

Comment: @Nibr yes, it is. But I can't disable sandboxing.

Comment: MacOS places the sandbox data in /Users/<Username>/Library/Containers/<Extension Bundle Identifier>/ that's why you get that URL. You could try to define a File Access Temporary Exception to the directory you need to access.